# swift indicator 自作

Tags: swift, ios

現状svprogressHudでindicatorを出しているのですが
画像を用意してそれをつなぎ合わせてアニメーションのように表示し
indicatorが表示される部分のアニメーションを独自のものにしたいのですが
方法がわかりません、教えて頂けると幸いです。

やってみたこととしてはクラス化をしてどこからでも使えるようにしたい為
xibとswiftファイルを作成し、クラス化をしてみました。
しかし、呼び出す際呼び出し側のviewと繋がりを認識できない為fatal errorが発生してしまいます。

svprogressHudをカスタマイズして画像を入れたりはできるのでしょうか？

Comment: サードパーティ製のライブラリを使うのであれば、[ドキュメント](https://github.com/SVProgressHUD/SVProgressHUD/blob/master/README.md)をよく読みましょう。画像や画像のリストで動作をカスタマイズするようなメソッドは用意されていないのがわかるかと思います。別のライブラリを探すか、ご自身でアニメーションを実装する必要があるでしょう。

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/214412

Comment: タイトルを編集されたことで、「`SVProgressHud`が簡単にカスタマイズできないのであれば、自作したい」ということだろうと推察するのですが、本文が全く更新されていないこともあり、その辺が不明確です。さらに「呼び出す際呼び出し側のviewと繋がりを認識できない為fatal errorが発生して」の部分、一体何をどうやろうとして何が起こったのか読んでも全くわかりません。サードパーティ製のライブラリを使うにしても、ご自身でApple製の部品を組み合わせて使うにしても、どちらにしろ起こりうることっぽく見えるので、一旦置いといて、(この問題が解決した後にでも)別質問とされた方がいいように思います。また現在の画面構成や、view controllerのコードなど、「ご自身がこれまで何をしたのか、どこで詰まっているのか」がわかるような情報をご質問に含めた方が、より詳細な回答がより早く得られるという傾向があります。「編集」ではご質問本文も編集できますので、「今現在一番聞きたいことは何なのか」「自分ではどこまでやれたのか」など、必要な情報を追加してみてください。